# How to put video and picture on same position?

Tags: html, css

here you can see that two circles stand separately, how can i put them in same position

[image]

here css code of two circles, indicated `position:relative` for `.player` class, and `.player__video`, and absolute for player1 and player2, but nothing is changed

```
.player {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .player {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
.player1{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
}
.player__video {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .player__video{
        display:none;
    }  
}
.player2
{
  overflow: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .player__video, .player2 {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
.player__video{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
       object-fit: cover;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;     
}
.player2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
       object-fit: cover;
    max-height: 100%;
 }
```

what should i change in this code?

here html code:

```
<div class="hero__player">
    <div class="player">
        <video class="player__video" width="506" height="506" muted preload="auto">
           <source src="[xfvalue_videopath]" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <div class= "player1">
            <img class="player2" src=[xfvalue_videopathimage] width="506" height="506">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

In the HTML code I created a `player` class, inside it there are two classes that are responsible for pictures and video

Answer (score 0):

You can place them on top of each other with `postition: absolute`

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}

/* Places the last image a off to show they are on top of each other */
img:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="">
```

You can use `z-index` to allow the click to reach the player button.

Hope this helps a bit.

[**JSFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/runcz0g3/1/)